# How can I filter query in array?

Tags: mongodb

My data in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(411694285),
    "transactionDataList" : [ 
        "{\"key\":\"6b8020acd2fdf393e67459dcb5d241cd2\",\"txaction\":\"appoint\",\"portalid\":\"2027601\",\"aid\":\"2344\",\"clearingtype\":\"sb\",\"notify_version\":\"7.4\",\"txtime\":\"32414\",\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"userid\":\"2324035\",\"accessname\":\"\",\"accesscode\":\"\",\"param\":\"cohort-496666-0-0-12\",\"mode\":\"live\",\"price\":\"169.95\",\"id\":{\"1\":\"Tei\"},\"pr\":{\"1\":\"169.95\"},\"no\":{\"1\":\"1\"},\"de\":{\"1\":\"Te 12 Monate\"},\"ti\":{\"1\":\"Te12 Monate\"},\"va\":{\"1\":\"19.00\"},\"txid\":\"4132432285\",\"reference\":\"4906-65a84dsdf3\",\"sequencenumber\":\"1\",\"company\":\"\",\"firstname\":\"Max\",\"lastname\":\"Mustermann\",\"street\":\"Weg 37\",\"zip\":\"33333\",\"city\":\"Moll",\"email\":\"muster@gmail.de\",\"country\":\"DE\",\"customerid\":\"2342\",\"balance\":\"0\",\"receivable\":\"111.95\"}"
    ],
    "_class" : "de.xxxx.creatinginvoice.model.TransactionModel"
}
```

I want to filter my data in MongoDB. Like:

```
db.getCollection('transaction').find({"transactionDataList":{$elemMatch: { "lastname":"Mustermann" } }});
```

But I got always no data after filtering. Don't know, why.

Comment: Looks like the element inside the array is a JSON string. The query will only provide the expected output if its a JSON object

Comment: I am using the Java Framework spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to insert the data into mongoDB. The element inside the array is mapping to class. Maybe it is JSON string. Ok how can i filter it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "transactionDataList.lastname": "Mustermann"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TzvQgmNUYSQ)

Comment: It is not working. I think the element inside the array is a JSON string.

Comment: yes, I am using java framework spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to insert the data in mongodb